# Find all records which have a count of an association greater than zero

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to do something that I thought it would be simple but it seems not to be.

I have a project model that has many vacancies.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :vacancies, :dependent => :destroy

end
```

I want to get all the projects that have at least 1 vacancy.
I tried something like this:

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).where('count(vacancies) > 0')
```

but it says

`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: vacancies: SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "vacancies" ON "vacancies"."project_id" = "projects"."id" WHERE ("projects"."deleted_at" IS NULL) AND (count(vacancies) > 0)`.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`joins` uses an inner join by default so using `Project.joins(:vacancies)` will in effect only return projects that have an associated vacancy.

UPDATE:

As pointed out by @mackskatz in the comment, without a `group` clause, the code above will return duplicate projects for projects with more than one vacancies.  To remove the duplicates, use

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id')
```

UPDATE:

As pointed out by @Tolsee, you can also use `distinct`.

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).distinct
```

As an example

```
[10] pry(main)> Comment.distinct.pluck :article_id
=> [43, 34, 45, 55, 17, 19, 1, 3, 4, 18, 44, 5, 13, 22, 16, 6, 53]
[11] pry(main)> _.size
=> 17
[12] pry(main)> Article.joins(:comments).size
=> 45
[13] pry(main)> Article.joins(:comments).distinct.size
=> 17
[14] pry(main)> Article.joins(:comments).distinct.to_sql
=> "SELECT DISTINCT \"articles\".* FROM \"articles\" INNER JOIN \"comments\" ON \"comments\".\"article_id\" = \"articles\".\"id\""
```

Comment: However, without applying a group by clause this would return multiple Project objects for Projects that have more than one Vacancy.

Comment: Doesn't generate an efficient SQL statement, though.

Comment: Well that is Rails for you.  If you can provide an sql answer (and explain why this isn't efficient), that may be a lot more helpful.

Comment: What do you think about `Project.joins(:vacancies).distinct`?

Comment: @Tolsee yes that would work too.  will update the answer

Comment: It's @Tolsee btw :D

Answer (score 215):

1) To get Projects with at least 1 vacancy:

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id')
```

2) To get Projects with more than 1 vacancy:

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id').having('count(project_id) > 1')
```

3) Or, if `Vacancy` model sets counter cache:

```
belongs_to :project, counter_cache: true
```

then this will work, too:

```
Project.where('vacancies_count > ?', 1)
```

Inflection rule for `vacancy` may need to be [specified manually](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html)?

Comment: Should this not be `Project.joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id').having('count(vacancies.id) > 1')`? Querying the number of vacancies instead of the project ids

Comment: No, @KeithMattix, it **should** not be. It **can** be, however, if it reads better to you; it's a matter of preference. The count can be done with any field in the join table that is guaranteed to have a value in every row. Most meaningful candidates are `projects.id`, `project_id`, and `vacancies.id`. I chose to count `project_id` because it is the field on which the join is made; the spine of the join if you will. It also reminds me that this is a join table.

Answer (score 44):

Yeah, `vacancies` is not a field in the join.  I believe you want:

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).group("projects.id").having("count(vacancies.id)>0")
```

Answer (score 28):

```rb
# None:
Project.left_joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id').having('count(vacancies) = 0')
# Any
Project.joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id').having('count(vacancies) > 0')
# One
Project.joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id').having('count(vacancies) = 1')
# More than 1
Project.joins(:vacancies).group('projects.id').having('count(vacancies) > 1')
```

Answer (score 8):

Performing an inner join to the has_many table combined with a `group` or `uniq` is potentially very inefficient, and in SQL this would be better implemented as a semi-join that uses `EXISTS` with a correlated subquery.

This allows the query optimiser to probe the vacancies table to check for the existence of a row with the correct project_id. It doesn't matter whether there is one row or a million that have that project_id.

That's not as straightforward in Rails, but can be achieved with:

```
Project.where(Vacancies.where("vacancies.project_id = projects.id").exists)
```

Similarly, find all projects that have no vacancies:

```
Project.where.not(Vacancies.where("vacancies.project_id = projects.id").exists)
```

Edit: in recent Rails versions you get a deprecation warning telling you to not to rely on `exists` being delegated to arel. Fix this with:

```
Project.where.not(Vacancies.where("vacancies.project_id = projects.id").arel.exists)
```

Edit: if you're uncomfortable with raw SQL, try:

```
Project.where.not(Vacancies.where(Vacancy.arel_table[:project_id].eq(Project.arel_table[:id])).arel.exists)
```

You can make this less messy by adding class methods to hide the use of `arel_table`, for example:

```
class Project
  def self.id_column
    arel_table[:id]
  end
end
```

... so ...

```
Project.where.not(
  Vacancies.where(
    Vacancy.project_id_column.eq(Project.id_column)
  ).arel.exists
)
```

Comment: these two suggestions don't seem to work... the subquery `Vacancy.where("vacancies.project_id = projects.id").exists?` yields either `true` or `false`. `Project.where(true)` is an `ArgumentError`.

Comment: `Vacancy.where("vacancies.project_id = projects.id").exists?` is not going to execute – it will raise an error because the `projects` relation won't exist in the query (and there's no question mark in the sample code above either).

So decomposing this into two expressions isn't valid and doesn't work.

In recent Rails `Project.where(Vacancies.where("vacancies.project_id = projects.id").exists)` raises a deprecation warning ... I'll update the question.

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 4+, you can also use **includes** or **eager_load** to get the same answer:

```
Project.includes(:vacancies).references(:vacancies).
        where.not(vacancies: {id: nil})

Project.eager_load(:vacancies).where.not(vacancies: {id: nil})
```

Answer (score 5):

I think there's a simpler solution:

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).distinct
```

Comment: It's also possible to use "distinct", e.g. Project.joins(:vacancies).distinct

Comment: You are right! It's better to use #distinct instead of #uniq. #uniq will load all objects into memory, but #distinct will do calculations on a database side.

Answer (score 4):

Without much Rails magic, you can do:

```
Project.where('(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vacancies WHERE vacancies.project_id = projects.id) > 0')
```

This type of conditions will work in all Rails versions as much of the work is done directly on the DB side. Plus, chaining `.count` method will work nicely too. I've been burned by queries like `Project.joins(:vacancies)` before. Of course, there are pros and cons as it's not DB agnostic.

Comment: This is much slower than join and group method, as the 'select count(*)..' subquery will execute for each projects.

Comment: @YasirAzgar The join and group method is slower than the "exists" method because it will still access all the child rows, even if there are a million of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `EXISTS` with `SELECT 1` rather than selecting all the columns from the `vacancies` table:

```
Project.where("EXISTS(SELECT 1 from vacancies where projects.id = vacancies.project_id)")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I want to know how many records have at least one of an associated record, I would do:

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).uniq.count
```

Answer (score -6):

The error is telling you that vacancies is not a column in projects, basically.

This should work

```
Project.joins(:vacancies).where('COUNT(vacancies.project_id) > 0')
```

Comment: `aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE`