# Rails 4 "where"-query with "has_many belongs_to"-relationship, searching with specific count

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

This should be a simple query, but I'm having problems getting the Rails syntax right. I'm using Rails 4.1.1 and Postgresql(9.3). I have a model User, and model Company. User has one company, and Company has many users. I'm trying to find all companies that have more than 5 users.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
   ...

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :company
   ...
```

Question is similar to this: [Find all records which have a count of an association greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183710/find-all-records-which-have-a-count-of-an-association-greater-than-zero)

If I try similar solution as mentioned above:

```
Company.joins(:users).group("company.id").having("count(users.id)>5")
```

It gives me an error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "company"
LINE 1: ... "users"."company_id" = "companies"."id" GROUP BY company.id...
```

I've tried several different queries for getting the result, but I've failed to do so. I could use SQL, but it seems dumb as this should be doable easily with ActiveRecord.

Thanks for all the replies :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should use `"companies.id"` instead of `"company.id"`.

```
Company.joins(:users).group("companies.id").having("count(users.id)>5")
```

And if you want to get company with 0 users, you have to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN users ON companies.id = users.company_id').group("companies.id").having("count(users.id) = 0")
```

Comment: I swear I tried with that as well, I guess not... Thanks a lot :) 

Somehow it's not working if there I'm trying a query with 0 users, with the query being like: 

Company.joins(:users).group("companies.id").having("count(users.id)=0") 


There's a company with 0 users, but it is still returning empty 
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 

Is there a different way it's supposed to be done, if trying to search with 0 users?

Comment: I wonder why this query returns a company with 8 users? 

    2.1.2p95 :115 > Company.joins('LEFT JOIN users ON companies.id = users.id').group("companies.id").having("count(users.id) = 0").first.users.count
 => 8

Comment: instead of `LEFT JOIN` which I think looks ugly in query syntax why not just use `includes(:users)` this will create a `LEFT JOIN` for you and looks much cleaner.

Comment: @MatiasP Sorry, have miss in join condition, now it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The query xdazz provided works well for when I'm trying to look for companies that have more than 0 users (basicly what I asked in initial post). I found two ways to do the search 0 users. One is the way noted above:

```
Company.joins('LEFT JOIN users ON companies.id = users.company_id')
.group("companies.id").having("count(users.id) = 0")
```

However with help of [Want to find records with no associated records in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319400/want-to-find-records-with-no-associated-records-in-rails-3/5570221#5570221) this is another way to do it:

```
Company.includes(:users).where(:users => {company_id=>nil})
```

Comment: `Company.joins('LEFT JOIN users ON companies.id = users.id')` should be `Company.joins('LEFT JOIN users ON companies.id = users.company_id')
 `

Comment: Right, I didn't pay proper attention there to notice it. I'll edit the post to show both ways.