# Rails find all records except already second level associated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have the following models in my rails application

Model `community`:

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :community_program
end
```

Model `community_program`:

```
class CommunityProgram < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program_name
end
```

Model `program_name`:

```
class ProgramName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :community_programs
end
```

I am trying to find a way to pull all the `program_names` which don't belong to a `community_program` which has already been assigned to a `community`.

I have been able to pull all `program_names` and then remove the `program_names` which are already associated with a `community` but that is very expensive. Can I directly pull the second level unassociated records?

**EDIT: The question is different from the linked question since in this case, `program_name` might have an association with a Community Program for a different community but we still want to include that name if it doesn't have an association with the current `community`.**

**EDIT 2: I want to extract all the Program Names which haven’t yet been assigned to a Community Program associated with a particular Community. They can be associated with the Community Programs associated with a different community. The use case is that a user should be able to select a name from the list of remaining names and assign that to a community program associated with their community.

Program names are global and although the program name for community programs of a particular community are unique but different communities can have community programs associated to the same program name**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all records which have a count of an association greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183710/find-all-records-which-have-a-count-of-an-association-greater-than-zero)

Comment: @JoshBrody I don’t think it’s a duplicate because they can have other associations I just want to ensure that they are not associated to the specific community through a community program but the same name can be connected to different community

Comment: Can you rephrase what you need to do? I understand this: You need all `ProgramName` that are 1) NOT associated  with any `CommunityProgram` and 2) Already associated with a `Community` ??

Comment: By the way, I think you're missing an association in your `CommunityProgram` model , a `belongs_to :community`

Comment: @gasc yes you are correct there is a missing association. I am using Stackoverflow on mobile so I can’t edit it but the association should be ther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `except_community` is a particular `Community` which associations should be excluded. Code below will produce one SQL query:

```
except_relation = except_community.
  community_programs.
  select(:program_name_id)

ProgramName.
  where.not(id: except_relation)
```

You can add it as an instance method of `Community` model.

Comment: If possible can you please explain why `select` is better than `pluck` in this situation even though `pluck` is supposed to be more efficient in general?

Comment: `pluck` is not supposed to be more efficient in general :) The `select` is not `Enumerable#select` but chainable method of `ActiveRecord::Relation` like `where`, `order` etc. So, `except_relation = ...` does not produce real SQL query(like `pluck`) but just builds instance of `ActiveRecord::Relation`. And so last lines of code look like `Model.where.not(id: ar_relation)` which produces one SQL query like `SELECT * FROM program_names WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT program_name_id FROM ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :community_programs
end

class CommunityProgram < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :program_name, optional: true
  belongs_to :community
end

class ProgramName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :community_programs
end

some_community            = Community.find some_community_id
programs_from_a_community = some_community.community_programs.map &:id 
program_names_to_exclude  = CommunityProgram.where(id: programs_from_a_community)
                                            .where.not(program_name_id: nil)
                                            .map { |c_p| c_p.program_name.id }
program_names             = ProgramName.where.not(id: program_names_to_exclude)
```

Answer (score 0):

My edition for the answer I accepted earlier was rejected so I am adding it as another answer. The solution provided by Pavel Mikhailyuk fixed my issue.

Since I wanted to find the most efficient query I could so I ended up updating it and using:

```
ProgramName.where.not(id: except_community.community_programs.pluck(:program_name_id))
```

EDIT: The selected answer is the more efficient than this.

Comment: Thank you for edit proposal, I've updated my answer with grammar fixes.

Comment: You are wrong with your assumption: `select` in my answer does NOT build any ActiveRecord model instance, just ActiveRecord relation. My example produces only ONE sql query with SUB-select, when `pluck` one produces TWO sql queries and depends on `program_name_id` count. So, my answer "is more efficient" than `pluck` one :)

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk Yes, you are correct. My reasoning was flawed over here and running a `to_sql` followed with benchmarking clearly showed that `select` is more efficient in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this a few different ways, depending on which controller/view you are displaying them on.

Create an [association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-many) on the Community model:

```
has_many :unassigned_program_names, -> { where community_program_id: nil }
```

Create a [scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) like this on the ProgramName model:

```
scope :unassigned, -> { where(community_program_id: nil) }
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: `community_program` belongs to a `program_name` so I don't think I can create the scope you have described above.