# Rails efficient way to find user with only one shareholder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In my method I want to check if user has only one shareholder, if it so it should return `true` (later on it's used in `if` block). Basically it should reflect something like `User.find_by(id: user.id).shareholder.count < 1` because it overloads the database with unnecessary queries (I have db with ~30k users).

What I was thinking is to create queries with `where` so I have this one:

```
def one_shareholder?(shareholder)
  ShareholdersUser.where(user_id: shareholder.owner_id).
                   where.not(shareholder_id: shareholder.id).exists?
end
```

But I don't know how to implement query which will be counting if this user has only one shareholder. Should I use something like `find_each` ?

Edit:

`user has_many :shareholder`

`shareholder belongs_to :owner`

`ShareholdersUser belongs_to :user and :shareholder`

Comment: can you please explain the association between your tables so that we can understand properly?

Comment: Ok, now it should be more clear I guess

Comment: can you please try the following answer?

Comment: Read more on counter cache https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache

Comment: I think counter cache might be useful for your use case

Comment: It works @Vishal but like I mentioned - I don't want to overloads the database with unnecessary queries. It should be really fast, this db has close to 30k users and your solution is pretty much the same as I mentioned in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can give you an hint. I used something similar in a project where I have these models:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :permits
end
```

and

```
class Permit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

For  fetching companies having just one permit I used:

```
Company.joins(:permits).group('companies.id').having('count(company_id) = 1')
```

---

Maybe you can pluck the ids and use the array to check wether the company is in the array. For example:

```
ids_of_companies_having_one_permit = Company.joins(:permits).group('companies.id').having('count(company_id) = 1').pluck(:id)
```

Then check:

```
if ids_of_companies_having_one_permit.include? company.id ....
```

---

This is the thread I followed: [Find all records which have a count of an association greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183710/find-all-records-which-have-a-count-of-an-association-greater-than-zero)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you are finding user from his `ID` then can directly use `User.find(user.id)` instead of `User.find_by(id: user.id)`

Secondly, As you mentioned in your question that you want either true/false for your if condition.

And as per your query I think you have `user has_many shareholder` association implemented.

So you can directly use `User.find(user.id).shareholders < 1` in your if condition like below,

```
if User.find(user.id).shareholders.count < 1
     #do something...
end
```

Note: I've used the plural of the shareholder in condition because we have has_many association

Comment: Yes but if you have more than 20k or 30k users, I think this query is not very efficient. It does pretty much the same as `User.find_by(id: user.id).shareholder.count < 1` which I mentioned earlier.