# Find all records which have a count of an association of zero and none-zero

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :associated_images, as: :imageable
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :associated_images, as: :imageable
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :associated_images
end

class AssociatedImage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :image
end
```

I'd like to get all the images which are being used, and a different query to get all the images that are not being used (based on `AssociatedImage`).

I tried `Image.joins(:associated_images).group('images.id').having('count(image_id) > 0')` and it returns the correct result. But when I run `Image.joins(:associated_images).group('images.id').having('count(image_id) = 0')`, it returns an empty `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>` and I'm not sure why is that.

My query is based off [Find all records which have a count of an association greater than zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20183710/find-all-records-which-have-a-count-of-an-association-greater-than-zero)'s discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that in SQL a count of zero happens when there are no rows.  So if there are no rows, even group, there is no result.

What you want is

```
Image.left_joins(:associated_images).where(associated_images: {id: nil}).group('images.id')
```

When SQL does a left join, for an image which does not have an associated image, it fills in NULL for all the columns in the `associated_images` table.  So the ones where the `associated_images.id` is nil, are the ones we want.